# Strange extra characters in Rails response body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, puma

I'm running rails application with Puma server and every response has some hex numbers at the start (looks like body length) and the end (always zero) of each response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: "8e6d795d26a3839c23c0b28f7b2e3c08"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: [skip]; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 741cdbde-39a8-4b99-9af7-15a7e65ff1ac
X-Runtime: 0.202731
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

f <-- THIS
{"response":{}}
0 <-- AND THIS
```

What is this?

Comment: Where do you see this request body?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the way *chunked* transfer encoding works. It sends the body in pieces, preceded by a line containing the length of the piece in hexadecimal. The end of the body is indicated by a chunk with `0` length.

So what you're showing is that the first chunk is 15 characters long, and there's no second chunk.

A proper HTTP client or API should strip these chunk headers out, and just return the contents.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) for more details, or [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) for the official spec.

Comment: See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-26.html#rfc.section.4.1 for the proper spec.

Comment: I've added a link to the RFC. I haven't compared, but I'll bet there's no substantive change to this section in the draft you linked to.

Comment: Also turns out that if you need to turn off chunked encoding, you just need to provide `Content-Length` header instead, and in Rails it's done by adding built-in middleware to the application config: `config.middleware.use Rack::ContentLength`